# SQL Query to set flag based on Start Date and Previous Close Date

Tags: sql, sql-query-store

I've tried searching this up, but nothing really matched with what I was looking for, so any help is appreciated!

[image]

And what I want is to have an Expression or flag which should return true if the number of days between previous **closed date** and current **Start date** is less than 10 for the **TASK ID**.

For Example The above table should looks like

[image]

Note:
I only have read-only access, so 'update queries' and 'create new table' queries are not applicable for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(close_date) over (partition by task_id) < dateadd(day, -10, close_date)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```